# Name Error when running a Python Script

Tags: python, program-entry-point

My code is

```
class GuessPassword(object):
      def generate_Parent(self,length):
              genes= []
              while len(genes) < length:
                   sampleSize = min(length - 
                       len(genes),len(self.__class__.geneSet))         
                   genes.extend(random.sample(self.__class__.geneSet, 
                              sampleSize))
             return ''.join(genes)
```

In My main method

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   random.seed()
   bestparent = self.generate_Parent( len(target))
```

and it's giving the error "NameError: name 'self' is not defined". And when I ran it without "self" it gave the error "NameError: name 'generate_Parent' is not defined".

I know it's a small issue. But I searched and couldn't find a solution. Any help would be great.

Comment: You cannot use self outside the Class method. So first use as below `bestparent = GuessPassword.generate_Parent( len(target))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `self` out of the class, also you need to make an `object` of the `GuessPassword` class, if you want to use class methods.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   random.seed()
   # bestparent = self.generate_Parent( len(target)) # here is error

   # make object of a class
   guess = GuessPassword()
   # remove `self` because you are not in a class, and use object instance
   bestparent = guess.generate_Parent( len(target))
```